# The limit could be changed via "languageserver.link_file_size_limit" option

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-irkernel

When I try to read in a csv file using

```
df<-read.csv("Regression_train.csv")
```

File size (17.6 Mb) exceeds the limit (16 Mb).
The limit could be changed via "languageserver.link_file_size_limit" option.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.Rprofile`:

```r
options(languageserver.link_file_size_limit = 20000)
```

The `20000` is the number of bytes. By default it's `16384` (16 Mb).

If you don't have a `.Rprofile` file, create a blank file called `.Rprofile` in your project directory and paste the above `options` line into it.